# Extract a union type of possible string values from nested arrays / objects within a readonly object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have a readonly / immutable object declared in TypeScript *like this:*

```js
const CoupeCar = {
  name: "Coupé",
  specs: {
    primary: [
      {
        name: "engine",
        value: "2.0L",
      },
      {
        name: "transmission",
        value: "6-speed",
      },
      {
        name: "color",
        value: "red",
      },
    ],
  },
} as const;
```

And a function to get one of the nested properties that looks *like this:*

```js
const getSpecForCoupeCar = (specName: string) => {
  return CoupeCar.specs.primary.find((spec) => spec.name === specName);
}
```

It would be great to be able to strictly type the `specName` argument so it is not a string, but a union type of e.g. either `"engine" | "transmission" | "color"`. However, I've been unable to construct a generic that does this because:

- Most generics that I've tried to write have involved the `typeof` keyword when in actuality I would like the constant's nested "values"
- The nested `primary` key is an array so I'm unable to access key names all the way down. I found a [generic here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965#issuecomment-354858633) (`type ValuesOf<T extends Readonly<any[]>>= T[number]`) but it suffers from the same issue of stripping the actual "values" I'd like to expose as it's converting them to types.

Is it even possible to "get" a union type from a nested array / object inside a readonly object in TypeScript? If I were able to express it as a generic there are lots of variations of the above pattern that I would benefit from type safety with.

Comment: You could do e.g. `typeof CoupeCar["specs"]["primary"][number]["name"]`, but you'd be far better off _actually defining a type_ so the compiler can help check your code.

Answer (score 1):

As similar to as above from @jonrsharpe

```js
type SpecNames = typeof CoupeCar.specs.primary[number]['name'];

const getSpecForCoupeCar = (specName: SpecNames) => {
  return CoupeCar.specs.primary.find((spec) => spec.name === specName);
}
```

Personally, I would change the data structure to have something more akin to

```js
specs: {
  primary: {
     engine: {
       ...engine specs
     },
     transmission: {
       ...transmission specs
     },
     color: {
       ...color specs etc (maybe multi panels with different colors - who knows)
     }
  }
}
```

to prevent dupes in the array, and then just grab directly from CoupeCar.specs.primary.

If you needed to do that through a function, the type becomes

```js
type SpecNames = keyof typeof CoupeCar.specs.primary;
```